# How to picture the cutline of $\Sigma = \mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading [2] and got stuck in interpretting the following statement at the end of Page 146.

> we 'cut' $\Sigma = \mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$ along the negative real line from $0$ to $\infty$ as in Fig.4.22 (See below), and the remaining region $E = \mathbb{C} - \{ z \in \mathbb{R} | z \leq 0 \}$...

[image]

Could someone explain why the cut line represents $z \leq 0$?

Any help would be appreciated!

### Reference

[2] Jones, Gareth A., and David Singerman. Complex functions: an algebraic and geometric viewpoint. Cambridge university press, 1987.

Comment: It is what they say just before: the negative real line from 0 to $\infty$, which is exactly the set $\{z\in\mathbb R\,|\,z\le 0\}$

Comment: hmm, sorry, but where would be the real line in this figure?? Besides, $0$ to $\infty$ is a `positive` part of the real line, right?

Comment: The negative real line is drawn, the positive real line not. If they would draw it, they would probably just continue the great circle to close it on $\infty$. But they could have used the same drawing for any line connecting 0 and $\infty$, e.g. the positive real axis, or the positive imaginary axis.

Comment: As for the point at $\infty$, that is not in any specific direction, it is in all directions. I don't know how they explicitly defined the geometrical structure on $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$, but it wouldn't look in any sense like a sphere if $\infty$ was in the direction of the positive real axis only.

Comment: Probably they mentioned stereographic projection

Comment: I think I'm getting there! So, suppose x-axis is associated w/h Real part of z and y-axis Imaginary part in the visualisation of $\mathbb{C}$. Then E is $\mathbb{C}$ without the negative part of x-axis! And on the sphere $\Sigma$ this E with the cutline looks like the one in the figure, right?

Comment: Exactly that! Here explicitly visualized as a subset of the Riemann sphere $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for your guide!

Comment: You're welcome!